# Informe en Crystal Report MVC .Net

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Tengo problemas al visualizar un reporte de crystal reports usando crystalreportviewer hecho en .net/C#, me muestra el toolbar pero no me trae el reporte.
Mirando por debajo el javascript que genera me muestra esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

<%-- <%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" 
namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>--%>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<%--   <script src="~/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js" type="text/javascript"> 
  </script>--%>
<script runat="server"> 

    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

        var row = new Web.Models.RptModels.NotaRemision();

        row.NumeroNota = "123";
        row.FechaEmision = "11/10/2017";
        row.TipoJugada = "Uno";
        row.FechaSorteo = "01/11/2017";
        row.Desde = "01";
        row.Hasta = "999";

        List<Web.Models.RptModels.NotaRemision> lista = new List<Web.Models.RptModels.NotaRemision>();
        lista.Add(row);

        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument CReport = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
        CReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/RptNotaRemision.rpt"));
        CReport.SetDataSource(lista);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CReport;
        //CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayToolbar = true;

    }

</script>
</head> 

<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div  style="height: 900px; width: 700px; ">
      <asp:Label ID="lblMensaje" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
AutoDataBind="True" HasRefreshButton="True"/>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Obs.: El dataset me trae datos.

Comment: Lograste resolver tu problema?